# How to show that a real continous function with image in the rationals is constant?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Can someone please explain to me how I am supposed to approach this question:

If $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{ R}$ is continuous, and has only rational values, then $f$ must be a constant.

Comment: Do you know the inetermediate value theorem?

Comment: I was thinking maybe using proof by contradiction. give me a minute and I will type it up

Comment: yes, I know the intermediate value theorem. how am I supposed to use it?

Comment: @Alex you retagging this changes the context. Look at the other questions of OP.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose $f$ takes on two values $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ for which $a\neq b$. What does the intermediate value theorem tell us?

Comment: it says that there is a c such that f(x_k) = c for some x_k in [0, 1] and also such that a < c < b. and also that c is in the rationals. but how does that show that f is constant?

Comment: @BilalJunaidy If says that for *any* $c\in(a,b)$ you can find some $x$ with $f(x)=c$. Also for irrational $c$. So a contradiction is found.

Comment: oh my god, now I get it. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a continuous image of a connected space should be connected.

Comment: could you please define a connected space since I haven't studied it

Comment: @BilalJunaidy A topological space $X$ is connected if there is no partition $X=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty disjoint open subsets of the space $X$.

Comment: I actually havent studied topology so I wont be able to use it. but thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{I}$ be the interval $[0,1]$. Since $f$ is continous on the inverval $\mathbf{I}$,
then $f(\mathbf{I})$ must be an interval. Now, suppose that $f(\mathbf{I})$ is the interval $[a,b]$, where *a, b* $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$. Since irrationals are dense, we can find a irrational number in the interval $[a,b]$. This is a contradiction because we know that $f(\mathbf{I})$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f(\mathbf{I})$ must be a degenerated inverval and therefore it takes a constant value.